# More effective way of calculating/adding new columns using Pandas for large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I have the following data set:

```
              CustomerID Date                     Amount           Department  \
0                 395134 2019-01-01               199              Home   
1                 395134 2019-01-01               279              Home   
2                1356012 2019-01-07               279              Home   
3                1921374 2019-01-08               269              Home   
4                 395134 2019-01-01               279              Home   
...                  ...        ...               ...               ...   
18926474         1667426 2021-06-30               349        Womenswear   
18926475         1667426 2021-06-30               299        Womenswear   
18926476          583105 2021-06-30               349        Womenswear   
18926477          538137 2021-06-30               279        Womenswear   
18926478          825382 2021-06-30              2499              Home   

                  DaysSincePurchase  
0                 986 days  
1                 986 days  
2                 980 days  
3                 979 days  
4                 986 days  
...                    ...  
18926474           75 days  
18926475           75 days  
18926476           75 days  
18926477           75 days  
18926478           75 days
```

I want to do some feature engineering and add a few columns after having aggregated (using group_by) by customerID. The Date column is unimportant and can easily be dropped. I want a data set where every row is one unique customerID which are just integers 1,2... (first col) where the other columns are:

1. Total amount of purchasing
2. Days since the last purchase
3. Number of total departments

This is what I've done, and it works. However when I time it, it takes about 1.5 hours. Is there another more efficient of doing this?

```
customer_group = joinedData.groupby(['CustomerID'])
n = originalData['CustomerID'].nunique()

# First arrange the data in a matrix.
matrix = np.zeros((n,5)) # Pre-allocate matrix

for i in range(0,n):
    matrix[i,0] = i+1
    matrix[i,1] = sum(customer_group.get_group(i+1)['Amount'])
    matrix[i,2] = min(customer_group.get_group(i+1)['DaysSincePurchase']).days
    matrix[i,3] = customer_group.get_group(i+1)['Department'].nunique()

# The above loop takes 6300 sec approx

# convert matrix to dataframe and name columns
newData = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
newData = newData.rename(columns = {0:"CustomerID"})
newData = newData.rename(columns = {1:"TotalDemand"})
newData = newData.rename(columns = {2:"DaysSinceLastPurchase"})
newData = newData.rename(columns = {3:"nrDepartments"})
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the dataset?

Comment: @Luke I put a picture of it in the post, is it not visible to you? Or do you mean uploading the whole data set? I can't upload it unfortunately.

Comment: If you could provide the entire dataset the SO Community would be able to develop an approach and compare it's performance with yours, else this question would be pretty pointless

Comment: @Luke - I totally understand and I wish I could. But sharing data files like this goes against company policy :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `agg`:

```
>>> df.groupby('CustomerID').agg(TotalDemand=('Amount', sum), 
                                 DaysSinceLastPurchase=('DaysSincePurchase', min),
                                 nrDepartments=('Department', 'nunique'))
```

I ran this function over a dataframe of 20,000,000 records. It took few seconds to be executed:

```
>>> %timeit df.groupby('CustomerID').agg(...)
14.7 s ± 225 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Generated data:

```
N = 20000000
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'CustomerID': np.random.randint(1000, 10000, N), 
     'Date': np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'), N),
     'Amount': np.random.randint(100, 1000, N),
     'Department': np.random.choice(['Home', 'Sport', 'Food', 'Womenswear',
                                     'Menswear', 'Furniture'], N)})
df['DaysSincePurchase'] = pd.Timestamp.today().normalize() - df['Date']
```